# Unable to cast/match types when using generics in interfaces, why?

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

In IMyMessage.cs

```
public interface IMyMessage
{
}
```

In IMyMessageReceiver.cs

```
public interface IMyMessageReceiver<T> where T: IMyMessage
{
    void HandleMessage(T message);
    void Subscribe();
}
```

In MyMessagePublisher.cs

```
public static class MyMessagePublisher
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, List<IMyMessageReceiver<IMyMessage>>> _subscribers;

    static MyMessagePublisher
    {
         _subscribers = new Dictionary<Type, List<IMyMessageReceiver<IMyMessage>>>();
    }

    public static function Subscribe<T>(IMyMessageReceiver<T> receiver) where T: IMyMessage
    {
        Type messageType = typeof (T);
        List<IMyMessageReceiver<IMyMessage>> listeners;

        if(!_subscribers.TryGetValue(messageType, out listeners))
        {
             // no list found, so create it
             List<IMyMessageReceiver<T>> newListeners = new List<IMyMessageReceiver<T>>();
             // ERROR HERE: Can't convert List<IMyMessageReceiver<T>> to List<IMyMessageReceiver<IMyMessage>>
             _subscribers.add(messageType, newListeners);

        }

        //  I would then find the right list and add the receiver it to it but haven't got this far
    }
}
```

So my hope was to use a bunch of 'IMyMessages' and 'IMyMessageReceivers' to pass messages around. I did a hard coded approach earlier but got sick of 100 different publish/subscrive function names so I figured I'd wrap it all nicely in generics.

My problem is that I can't get the code to work when using generics. Even though I specify the Type T will be of IMyMessage, I cannot use T anywhere where IMyMessage is expected. Maybe I'm just used to base/extended classes as it would work fine there. I've tried various approaches from casting, to being really generic, yet I always run in to the same issue.

Comment: You're trying to use `T` in a covariant way, but input parameters in C# can only be made contravariant

Comment: @Sean, is there a solution here then or should I just try create a MyMessage/MyMessageReceiver class and extend them instead? I don't really like the sound of that though as it adds some difficulties.

Comment: @Zeritor - I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK here's how I can see it working.  Since you're trying to use covariance in a way that is not supported, you'll need to avoid using generics in a few spots.  But doing so won't lose any type-safety.

Create a non-generic `IMessageReceiver` interface so that the types that can't use the generic parameter can use this instead:

```
public interface IMyMessageReceiver
{
    void HandleMessage(IMyMessage message);

    void Subscribe();
}

public interface IMyMessageReceiver<in T> : IMyMessageReceiver
    where T : IMyMessage
{
    void HandleMessage(T message);
}
```

You can create a base class to simplify things if you'd like:

```
public abstract class MyMessageReceiverBase<T> : IMyMessageReceiver<T>
    where T : IMyMessage
{
    public abstract void HandleMessage(T message);

    public void HandleMessage(IMyMessage message)
    {
        if (!(message is T))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        HandleMessage((T)message);
    }

    public abstract void Subscribe();
}
```

Then you can change `IMyMessageListeners` to use the non-generic version, since it doesn't really need the generic type anyways:

```
public interface IMyMessageListeners
{
    void Add(IMyMessageReceiver receiver);

    // I added this since I think this is how you're going to use it
    void Send(IMyMessage message);
}
```

The concrete of this class looks like this:

```
public class MyMessageListeners : IMyMessageListeners
{
    readonly List<IMyMessageReceiver> _list = new List<IMyMessageReceiver>();

    public void Add(IMyMessageReceiver receiver)
    {
        _list.Add(receiver);
    }

    public void Send(IMyMessage message)
    {
        foreach (var listener in _list)
            listener.HandleMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Then (finally), your static class will look like this:

```
public static class MyMessagePublisher
{
    static readonly Dictionary<Type, IMyMessageListeners> _subscribers = new Dictionary<Type, IMyMessageListeners>();

    // I added this too, since I think this is how you intend to use it
    public static void Publish<T>(T message) where T : IMyMessage
    {
        Type messageType = typeof(T);
        IMyMessageListeners listeners;

        if (_subscribers.TryGetValue(messageType, out listeners))
            listeners.Send(message);
    }

    public static void Subscribe<T>(IMyMessageReceiver<T> receiver) where T : IMyMessage
    {
        Type messageType = typeof(T);
        IMyMessageListeners listeners;

        if (!_subscribers.TryGetValue(messageType, out listeners))
        {
            // no list found, so create it
            listeners = new MyMessageListeners();
            _subscribers.Add(messageType, listeners);
        }

        listeners.Add(receiver);
    }
}
```

And you can use your static class like so:

```
MyMessagePublisher.Subscribe(new FooMessageReceiver());
MyMessagePublisher.Publish(new FooMessage());
```

Comment: Your solution is identical to using List<IMyMessageReceiver<IMyMessage>> which would work anyway. Would it work if using IMyMessageListeners<T> insted of IMyMessageListeners<IMyMessage> ?

Comment: Gah, you're right it is identical, and the `Add(receiver)` call doesn't work either way.  I'll rethink this but may withdraw my answer if I can't come up with anything.

Comment: What do in/out do in the '<T>' definition? If you don't think this works I will hold off trying it for now. I feel like I'm going about this all wrong.

Comment: `out` makes the type parameter "covariant", and `in` makes it "contravariant".  Too much to talk about in a comment, google it or [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Comment: @Zeritor I've changed my answer to something that works.

Comment: Hi @PatrickQuirk thanks for the answer. I have got further thanks to this. However, I'm trying to allow a class to be able to be a messenger of multiple types but it won't let me use MyMessageReceiverBase<T> twice! C# only allows multiple inheritance using Interfaces D:

Comment: @Zeritor You could create an interface `IMyMessageReceiver<T1,T2> : IMyMessageReceiver<T1>` and add the method `HandleMessage(T2 message)`.  You'd need to make a similar base class, but that would get you what you want I'd think

Comment: I also seem to be able to do: `class myClass : MyMessageReceiver<T1>, IMyMessageReceiver<T2> ... IMyMessageReceiver<Tn>` and then just make sure that `myClass` has definitions for `HandleMessage<T1> ... HandleMessage<Tn>`. I now have it working from end to end, so thank you very much @PatrickQuirk

Answer (score 0):

Generics do not support covariance. Therfore IMyMessageReceiver T cannot be cast into IMyMessageReceiver IMyMessage even if T implements IMyMessage. That is why you get your error.

I don't think you should use generics in IMyMessageReceiver interface. I am not sure about what you are trying to achieve but maybe something like that would do the trick:

```
public interface IMyMessageReceiver
{
    void HandleMessage(IMyMessage message);
    void Subscribe();
}

public class MyMessageReceiver<T> : IMyMessageReceiver where T: IMyMessage
{
    void IMyMessageReceiver.HandleMessage(IMyMessage message)
    {
        HandleMessage(message as T);
    }

    public void HandleMessage(T message) {...}
    public void Subscribe() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know the types will always be `IMyMessageReceiver<T>` you have emulate the behaviour by storing everthing as an object and casting:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _subscribers;


    public static function Subscribe<T>(IMyMessageReceiver<T> receiver) where T: IMyMessage
    {
      Type messageType = typeof (T);
      List<object> listeners;

      if(!_subscribers.TryGetValue(messageType, out listeners))
      {
        // no list found, so create it
        List<object> newListeners = new List<object>();
        newListeners.Add(receiver)
        _subscribers.add(messageType, newListeners);

      }

      var messageReceivers = listeners.Cast<IMyMessageReceiver<T>>();
}
```

Since you know the list in the dictionary will always be of a given type you can cast them with confidence!

Comment: The point of generics is to avoid using an ugly object container that is dynamically cast!

Comment: @AdrienBuet - yes, but sometimes you have to sell your soul!

Answer (score 0):

In this case `KeyedByTypeCollection<T>` is appropriate:

```
public interface IMyMessage
{
}

public interface IMyMessageReceiver<T> where T : IMyMessage
{
    void HandleMessage(T message);
    void Subscribe();
}

public static class MyMessagePublisher
{
    private static readonly KeyedByTypeCollection<IList> Subscribers;

    static MyMessagePublisher()
    {
        Subscribers = new KeyedByTypeCollection<IList>();
    }

    public static void Subscribe<T>(IMyMessageReceiver<T> receiver) where T : IMyMessage
    {
        List<IMyMessageReceiver<T>> listeners = Subscribers.Find<List<IMyMessageReceiver<T>>>();

        if (listeners == null)
        {
            listeners = new List<IMyMessageReceiver<T>>();
            Subscribers.Add(listeners);
        }

        // Now you can use the listeners list

        listeners.Add(receiver);
    }
}
```